# How to get HTML to work with emails sent to outlook?

Tags: html, outlook, gmail, jakarta-mail, html-email

I'm making a program that sends an email to students with a conformation number using their student Id number. All of our emails fit the same template, id@whatever, and that's sourced through outlook, and they blocked gmail for our student emails.

Anyway, I wrote an html email, and when I send it to gmail, everything shows up. When I send it to my student account to test what they'd see, I see only like a quarter of what's supposed to be there.

So my question is: Is there a way I can alter my HTML so that it shows everything on outlook.

What Gmail Looks like

[image]

What Outlook looks like (with "trust user" selected)

[image]

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body><div dir="ltr"><input name="cloudHQ__backup_css" type="hidden" value="       &amp;lt;style type=&quot;text/css&quot;&amp;gt;&#10;&#9;&#9;p{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;margin:10px 0;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;padding:0;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;table{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;border-collapse:collapse;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;display:block;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;margin:0;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;padding:0;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;img,a img{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;border:0;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;height:auto;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;outline:none;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;text-decoration:none;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;body,#bodyTable,#bodyCell{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;height:100%;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;margin:0;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;padding:0;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;width:100%;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;.mcnPreviewText{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;display:none !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;#outlook a{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;padding:0;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;img{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;table{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;mso-table-lspace:0pt;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;mso-table-rspace:0pt;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;.ReadMsgBody{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;width:100%;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;.ExternalClass{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;width:100%;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;p,a,li,td,blockquote{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;a[href^=tel],a[href^=sms]{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;color:inherit;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;cursor:default;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;text-decoration:none;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;p,a,li,td,body,table,blockquote{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;.ExternalClass,.ExternalClass p,.ExternalClass td,.ExternalClass div,.ExternalClass span,.ExternalClass font{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;line-height:100%;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;a[x-apple-data-detectors]{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;color:inherit !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;text-decoration:none !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-size:inherit !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-family:inherit !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-weight:inherit !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;line-height:inherit !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;#bodyCell{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;padding:10px;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;.templateContainer{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;max-width:600px !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;a.mcnButton{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;display:block;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;.mcnImage,.mcnRetinaImage{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;vertical-align:bottom;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;.mcnTextContent{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;word-break:break-word;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;.mcnTextContent img{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;height:auto !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;.mcnDividerBlock{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;table-layout:fixed !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;body,#bodyTable{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;background-color:#ddf1f2;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;#bodyCell{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;border-top:0;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;.templateContainer{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;border:0;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;h1{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;color:#202020;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-family:Helvetica;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-size:26px;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-style:normal;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-weight:bold;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;line-height:125%;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;letter-spacing:normal;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;text-align:left;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;h2{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;color:#202020;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-family:Helvetica;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-size:22px;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-style:normal;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-weight:bold;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;line-height:125%;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;letter-spacing:normal;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;text-align:left;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;h3{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;color:#202020;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-family:Helvetica;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-size:20px;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-style:normal;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-weight:bold;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;line-height:125%;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;letter-spacing:normal;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;text-align:left;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;h4{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;color:#202020;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-family:Helvetica;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-size:18px;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-style:normal;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-weight:bold;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;line-height:125%;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;letter-spacing:normal;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;text-align:left;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;#templatePreheader{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;background-color:#fafafa;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;background-image:none;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;background-repeat:no-repeat;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;background-position:center;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;background-size:cover;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;border-top:0;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;border-bottom:0;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;padding-top:10px;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;padding-bottom:0px;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;#templatePreheader .mcnTextContent,#templatePreheader .mcnTextContent p{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;color:#656565;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-family:Helvetica;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-size:12px;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;line-height:150%;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;text-align:left;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;#templatePreheader .mcnTextContent a,#templatePreheader .mcnTextContent p a{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;color:#898989;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-weight:normal;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;text-decoration:none;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;#templateHeader{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;background-color:#60c7c6;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;background-image:none;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;background-repeat:no-repeat;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;background-position:center;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;background-size:cover;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;border-top:0;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;border-bottom:0;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;padding-top:0px;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;padding-bottom:0px;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;#templateHeader .mcnTextContent,#templateHeader .mcnTextContent p{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;color:#202020;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-family:Helvetica;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-size:16px;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;line-height:150%;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;text-align:left;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;#templateHeader .mcnTextContent a,#templateHeader .mcnTextContent p a{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;color:#007C89;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-weight:normal;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;text-decoration:underline;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;#templateBody{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;background-color:#ffffff;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;background-image:url(&quot;https://gallery.mailchimp.com/ed526b2f15f645fc575e0db76/images/a3dde7f2-ddb4-49e0-a119-a523cf6237bd.jpg&quot;);&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;background-repeat:no-repeat;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;background-position:top;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;background-size:cover;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;border-top:0;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;border-bottom:2px solid #EAEAEA;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;padding-top:0;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;padding-bottom:0px;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;#templateBody .mcnTextContent,#templateBody .mcnTextContent p{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;color:#202020;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-family:Helvetica;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-size:16px;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;line-height:150%;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;text-align:left;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;#templateBody .mcnTextContent a,#templateBody .mcnTextContent p a{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;color:#007C89;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-weight:normal;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;text-decoration:none;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;#templateFooter{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;background-color:#fafafa;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;background-image:none;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;background-repeat:no-repeat;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;background-position:center;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;background-size:cover;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;border-top:0;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;border-bottom:0;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;padding-top:9px;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;padding-bottom:9px;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;#templateFooter .mcnTextContent,#templateFooter .mcnTextContent p{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;color:#656565;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-family:Helvetica;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-size:12px;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;line-height:150%;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;text-align:center;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;&#9;#templateFooter .mcnTextContent a,#templateFooter .mcnTextContent p a{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;color:#656565;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-weight:normal;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;text-decoration:none;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#9;@media only screen and (min-width:768px){&#10;&#9;&#9;.templateContainer{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;width:600px !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#10;}&#9;@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){&#10;&#9;&#9;body,table,td,p,a,li,blockquote{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#10;}&#9;@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){&#10;&#9;&#9;body{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;width:100% !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;min-width:100% !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#10;}&#9;@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){&#10;&#9;&#9;#bodyCell{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;padding-top:10px !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#10;}&#9;@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){&#10;&#9;&#9;.mcnRetinaImage{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;max-width:100% !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#10;}&#9;@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){&#10;&#9;&#9;.mcnImage{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;width:100% !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#10;}&#9;@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){&#10;&#9;&#9;.mcnCartContainer,.mcnCaptionTopContent,.mcnRecContentContainer,.mcnCaptionBottomContent,.mcnTextContentContainer,.mcnBoxedTextContentContainer,.mcnImageGroupContentContainer,.mcnCaptionLeftTextContentContainer,.mcnCaptionRightTextContentContainer,.mcnCaptionLeftImageContentContainer,.mcnCaptionRightImageContentContainer,.mcnImageCardLeftTextContentContainer,.mcnImageCardRightTextContentContainer,.mcnImageCardLeftImageContentContainer,.mcnImageCardRightImageContentContainer{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;max-width:100% !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;width:100% !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#10;}&#9;@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){&#10;&#9;&#9;.mcnBoxedTextContentContainer{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;min-width:100% !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#10;}&#9;@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){&#10;&#9;&#9;.mcnImageGroupContent{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;padding:9px !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#10;}&#9;@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){&#10;&#9;&#9;.mcnCaptionLeftContentOuter .mcnTextContent,.mcnCaptionRightContentOuter .mcnTextContent{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;padding-top:9px !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#10;}&#9;@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){&#10;&#9;&#9;.mcnImageCardTopImageContent,.mcnCaptionBottomContent:last-child .mcnCaptionBottomImageContent,.mcnCaptionBlockInner .mcnCaptionTopContent:last-child .mcnTextContent{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;padding-top:18px !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#10;}&#9;@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){&#10;&#9;&#9;.mcnImageCardBottomImageContent{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;padding-bottom:9px !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#10;}&#9;@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){&#10;&#9;&#9;.mcnImageGroupBlockInner{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;padding-top:0 !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;padding-bottom:0 !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#10;}&#9;@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){&#10;&#9;&#9;.mcnImageGroupBlockOuter{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;padding-top:9px !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;padding-bottom:9px !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#10;}&#9;@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){&#10;&#9;&#9;.mcnTextContent,.mcnBoxedTextContentColumn{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;padding-right:18px !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;padding-left:18px !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#10;}&#9;@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){&#10;&#9;&#9;.mcnImageCardLeftImageContent,.mcnImageCardRightImageContent{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;padding-right:18px !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;padding-bottom:0 !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;padding-left:18px !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#10;}&#9;@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){&#10;&#9;&#9;.mcpreview-image-uploader{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;display:none !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;width:100% !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#10;}&#9;@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){&#10;&#9;&#9;h1{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-size:22px !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;line-height:125% !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#10;}&#9;@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){&#10;&#9;&#9;h2{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-size:20px !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;line-height:125% !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#10;}&#9;@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){&#10;&#9;&#9;h3{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-size:18px !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;line-height:125% !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#10;}&#9;@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){&#10;&#9;&#9;h4{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-size:16px !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;line-height:150% !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#10;}&#9;@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){&#10;&#9;&#9;.mcnBoxedTextContentContainer .mcnTextContent,.mcnBoxedTextContentContainer .mcnTextContent p{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-size:14px !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;line-height:150% !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#10;}&#9;@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){&#10;&#9;&#9;#templatePreheader{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;display:block !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#10;}&#9;@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){&#10;&#9;&#9;#templatePreheader .mcnTextContent,#templatePreheader .mcnTextContent p{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-size:14px !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;line-height:150% !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#10;}&#9;@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){&#10;&#9;&#9;#templateHeader .mcnTextContent,#templateHeader .mcnTextContent p{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-size:16px !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;line-height:150% !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#10;}&#9;@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){&#10;&#9;&#9;#templateBody .mcnTextContent,#templateBody .mcnTextContent p{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-size:16px !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;line-height:150% !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#10;}&#9;@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){&#10;&#9;&#9;#templateFooter .mcnTextContent,#templateFooter .mcnTextContent p{&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;font-size:14px !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;&#9;line-height:150% !important;&#10;&#9;&#9;}&#10;&#10;}&amp;lt;/style&amp;gt;" /><center>
  <div>
    <div>
      <br />
    </div>
  </div>
  <table id="bodyTable" style="border-collapse:collapse;height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;width:100%;background-color:#333869" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="bodyCell" style="height:100%;margin:0;padding:10px;width:100%;border-top:0" align="center" valign="top">
          <table style="border-collapse:collapse;border:0;max-width:600px!important" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td id="templatePreheader" style="background:#fafafa none no-repeat center/cover;background-color:#fafafa;background-image:none;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;background-size:cover;border-top:0;border-bottom:0;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:0px" valign="top">
                  <table style="min-width:100%;border-collapse:collapse" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="padding:0px" valign="top">
                          <table style="min-width:100%;border-collapse:collapse" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:center;padding:0 0px 0 0px" valign="top">
                                  <div>
                                    <img src="https://share1.cloudhq-mkt3.net/images_1524368_e6020c61-2016-0138-74a3-64434b0c2d74_4580" alt="Untitled drawing.jpg" width="452" height="167" />
                                  </div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <table style="min-width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;table-layout:fixed!important" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="min-width:100%;padding:10px 18px 0px">
                          <table style="min-width:100%;border-top:2px solid #eaeaea;border-collapse:collapse;height:17px;width:100%" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr style="height:17px">
                                <td style="height:17px">&#xA0;</td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td id="templateHeader" style="background:#83c239 none no-repeat center/cover;background-color:#83c239;background-image:none;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;background-size:cover;border-top:0;border-bottom:0;padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px" valign="top">
                  <table style="min-width:100%;border-collapse:collapse" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="padding-top:9px" valign="top">
                          <table style="max-width:100%;min-width:100%;border-collapse:collapse" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td style="word-break:break-word;color:#202020;font-family:Helvetica;font-size:16px;line-height:150%;text-align:left;padding:0 18px 9px 18px" valign="top">
                                  <div style="text-align:center">
                                    <span style="font-size:20px">
                                      <span style="font-family:playfair display,georgia,times new roman,serif">
                                        <span style="color:#ffffff">Cookies for a Cause!</span>
                                      </span>
                                    </span>
                                  </div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td id="templateBody" style="background:#ffffff url('https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/Dug6Uf0z_gnLgMs2DNJtvfFYLpZA-FrE_Lr1190kkoiLRQhE8Ekh5ouP-pZ_ar107jt3hxS2ltdIEejWFfQ2ia2Tpk-tH5pbv-fUY6Q_lhty3GyTJiHbsr2cRMrQAJtpKTpz=s0-d-e1-ft#https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download\000026id=11pP7V1G-vwASU6vAwkOb0fCeL2GzNo_l') no-repeat top/cover;background-color:#ffffff;background-image:url('https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/Dug6Uf0z_gnLgMs2DNJtvfFYLpZA-FrE_Lr1190kkoiLRQhE8Ekh5ouP-pZ_ar107jt3hxS2ltdIEejWFfQ2ia2Tpk-tH5pbv-fUY6Q_lhty3GyTJiHbsr2cRMrQAJtpKTpz=s0-d-e1-ft#https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download\000026id=11pP7V1G-vwASU6vAwkOb0fCeL2GzNo_l');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:top;background-size:cover;border-top:0;border-bottom:2px solid #eaeaea;padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0px" valign="top">
                  <table style="min-width:100%;border-collapse:collapse" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="padding-top:9px" valign="top">
                          <table style="max-width:100%;min-width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;height:96px;width:95.8865%" border="0" width="449" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr style="height:96px">
                                <td style="padding:0px 18px 9px;line-height:200%;word-break:break-word;text-align:left;height:96px" valign="top">
                                  <div style="text-align:center">
                                    <span style="font-size:36pt">
                                      <span style="text-align:left">
                                        <span style="color:#ffffff;font-family:arvo,courier,georgia,serif">
                                          <br />
                                        </span>
                                      </span>
                                    </span>
                                  </div>
                                  <div style="text-align:center">
                                    <span style="font-size:36pt">
                                      <span style="text-align:left">
                                        <span style="color:#ffffff;font-family:arvo,courier,georgia,serif">
                                          <br />
                                        </span>
                                      </span>
                                    </span>
                                  </div>
                                  <div style="text-align:center">
                                    <span style="font-size:36pt">&#xA0; 
                                      <span style="text-align:left">
                                        <span style="color:#ffffff;font-family:arvo,courier,georgia,serif">
                                          <br />
                                        </span>
                                      </span>
                                    </span>
                                  </div>
                                  <div style="text-align:center">
                                    <span style="font-size:36pt">
                                      <span style="text-align:left">
                                        <span style="color:#ffffff;font-family:arvo,courier,georgia,serif">ENVIRONMENTAL</span>
                                      </span> 
                                      <span style="color:#202020;font-family:Helvetica">
                                        <span style="font-family:arvo,courier,georgia,serif">
                                          <span style="color:#ffffff">CLUB</span>
                                        </span>
                                      </span>
                                    </span>
                                  </div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <table style="min-width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;table-layout:fixed!important" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="min-width:100%;padding:0px 18px">
                          <table style="min-width:100%;border-top:1px solid #ffffff;border-collapse:collapse;height:17px;width:100%" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr style="height:17px">
                                <td style="height:17px">&#xA0;</td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <table style="min-width:100%;border-collapse:collapse" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="padding-top:9px" valign="top">
                          <table style="max-width:100%;min-width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;height:45px;width:100%" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr style="height:45px">
                                <td style="padding:0px 18px 9px;line-height:200%;word-break:break-word;color:#202020;font-family:Helvetica;font-size:16px;text-align:left;height:45px" valign="top">
                                  <div style="text-align:center">
                                    <span style="font-size:20px">
                                      <span style="font-family:arvo,courier,georgia,serif">
                                        <span style="color:#ffffff">Confirmation Number:</span>
                                      </span>
                                    </span>
                                  </div>
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <table style="min-width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;height:53px;width:100%" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr style="height:36px">
                        <td style="text-align:center;padding:0px 18px 18px;height:36px" align="center" valign="top">
                          <span style="color:#ffffff">
                            <span style="font-size:48px">ConNum</span>
                          </span>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr style="height:17px">
                        <td style="padding:0px 18px 18px;height:17px">
                          <span style="color:#008080">
                            <br />
                          </span>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                  <table style="min-width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;table-layout:fixed!important;height:17px;width:100%" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr style="height:17px">
                        <td style="min-width:100%;padding:150px 18px 0px;height:17px">&#xA0;
                          <br />
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td id="templateFooter" style="background:none center center/cover no-repeat #fafafa;border-top:0px;border-bottom:0px;padding-top:9px;padding-bottom:9px;text-align:center" valign="top">
                  <a href="mailto:rrhsenvironmentals@gmail.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Contact us</a> 
                  <br />
                  <table style="min-width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;table-layout:fixed!important;height:36px;width:102.542%" border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr style="height:36px">
                        <td style="min-width:100%;padding:10px 18px 25px;height:36px;width:100%">
                          <table style="min-width:100%;border-top:2px solid #eeeeee;border-collapse:collapse;height:34px;width:100.224%" border="0" width="448" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tbody>
                              <tr style="height:17px">
                                <td style="height:17px">
                                  <br />
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr style="height:17px">
                                <td style="height:17px">&#xA0;</td>
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</center>
<br clear="all" />
<div>
  <br />
</div>
<div dir="ltr" data-smartmail="gmail_signature">
  <div dir="ltr">
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please Keep in mind I know basic Java, and little to no HTML, I used a web builder for this. So any explanations would be better received written with a 5 year old in mind. I'm really enjoying learning to program, and really want to keep doing it, so please put up with my lack of knowledge.

Comment: Turnip is incorrect. Outlook does support background images, however you need to do a little extra work to make it render. See @gwally's complete answer to see what to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook does not work with `background-image`. To get an image into the background of an Outlook email, you have to use `vml`.

**VML Sample**

```
 <table>
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" style="text-align: center; background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/600x230/222222/666666'); background-color: #222222; background-position: center center !important; background-size: cover !important;">
            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
            <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;height:175px; background-position: center center !important;">
            <v:fill type="tile" src="https://via.placeholder.com/600x230/222222/666666" color="#222222" />
            <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
            <![endif]-->
            <div>
                <table role="presentation" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="middle" style="text-align: center; padding: 40px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #ffffff;">
                            <p style="margin: 0;">Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Praesent laoreet malesuada cursus. Maecenas scelerisque congue eros eu posuere. Praesent in felis ut velit pretium lobortis rhoncus ut&nbsp;erat.</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <!--[if gte mso 9]>
            </v:textbox>
            </v:rect>
            <![endif]-->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Invalid Image Path**

In addition, your image path is not valid. This image url is not visible to me, which means it's not visible to anyone but you:

```
https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/Dug6Uf0z_gnLgMs2DNJtvfFYLpZA-FrE_Lr1190kkoiLRQhE8Ekh5ouP-pZ_ar107jt3hxS2ltdIEejWFfQ2ia2Tpk-tH5pbv-fUY6Q_lhty3GyTJiHbsr2cRMrQAJtpKTpz=s0-d-e1-ft#https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download\000026id=11pP7V1G-vwASU6vAwkOb0fCeL2GzNo_l
```

For this email to work, you need a url that is visible to email clients. You should use an Absolute File Path.

```
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg" alt="Mountain">
```

In general, the image should end with a descriptor that explains the image type such as: `.jpg`, `.png` or `.gif`. I am saying this, even though my sample doesn't use one, but that's because placeholder.com has engineered urls to work. Other hosts may not offer the capability.

**Further Reading**

- https://backgrounds.cm
- https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp
- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/color-background/background-image/

Good luck.